# Tv shows lower res than PC is outputting

Tags: graphics-card, resolution, hdmi, dvi, tv

I just upgraded my graphics card, on the old one I used a dvi-I to vga adapter to my tv, however if i tried using an HDMI cable I got the proplem where the tv would show a pixzelated screen, I assumed this was a problem with the graphics card. On the new one however there is no dvi-I port only dvi-D, so I have to use HDMI since my tv has no dvi input. However the same problem that happened to my old card still happens. It also overscans, I have tried two different cables with the same result. I have tested that the PC is outputting the correct resulotion by taking a screenshot.

TV: grundig 32 vlc6123 t2

Old GPU: AMD HD 7850

New GPU: AMD r9 390

Resulotion: 1920 x 1080

EDIT: The tv says that the signal is 1080p@60Hz

Comment: I found no fix for a over week so I just ordered a new monitor... I have no idea why this happened I tried all the tv settings, I am still interested in why this happened so if you know feel free to post.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you need to adjust the TV settings for that HDMI input to get rid of the overscan and pixelation.  Ensure that the TV isn't set to "expand" or "magnify" the picture.

Comment: My TV has no DVI input, only VGA and HDMI.

Comment: HDMI will work fine foe 1080p anyway. Check what resolution your PC thinks your TV is that could be the issue. Go to control panel then Screen resolution. Make sure your tv is set at 1920x1080

Comment: It is set 1920x1080

Comment: have you tried a different monitor to ensure it's not the GPU?

Comment: It has happened to both my gpus so I dont think it's the gpus.

Comment: what are you showing on the screen, a film or live stream?

Comment: @BunnyBoy Sorry, corrected the answer to show HDMI.  Same idea applies, though.

Comment: @ZeissIkon I Can't find any settings specifically for HDMI or any other settings that seem useful.

Comment: @DavidGolding Just my computer desktop, I have tried in games aswell and the same happens.

Comment: I still need help btw.

Comment: Should I maybe just buy a monitor?

Comment: If your budget will cover it, that's almost certainly the easiest way out.

Comment: I just tried on a different TV and the same happens...

Comment: The nVidia Control Panel application has overscan etc. controls, but I'm not familiar with the AMD/Radeon controls -- last Radeon card I used was ten years ago, on Windows 98.  You might check if there are similar settings in your driver controls.